# Unable to process .XLS file through Talend

Tags: talend

I am trying to push the data from .XLS file to my table using Talend, but wheb I create metadata using the .XLS file it is not recognizing and throwing "Unable to recognize OLE stream" error.
Even when I open same file in my local windows system it is throwing below error but when I click YES it is opening.
[image]

Please help me in processing the file using Talend.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the file extension to xlsx and then open it in Excel. Does it open without the warning ?

If so, then use a tFileInputExcel component to open it in Talend. Make sure the XLSX checkbox is enabled in that case .